# Flutter How to prevent child from Rotating with Parent?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to prevent a child Text from Rotating along with Parent?

This is sample code of what I have. I do not want the Text widget to rotate along with the parent Container. Is there an efficient way of doing it? Else I may have to wrap the child Text in another Transform.rotate and rotate it back.

```
class MyRotateContainer extends StatefulWidget {
@override
  _MyRotateContainerState createState() => new _MyRotateContainerState();
}

class _MyRotateContainerState extends State<MyRotateContainer> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Transform.rotate(
    angle: (30.0 * PI / 180.0),
    child: new Container(
      child: new Text(
        'SOME TEXT',
        textScaleFactor: 2.0,
      ),
    ));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the rotation problem is quite simple. You can add a second [Transform.rotate](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.rotate.html), wrapping your `Text` Widget as seen in the code below. I added red color to the `Container` to display the rotated `Container`.

Before adding the second rotate:
[image: Before adding 2nd rotate]

After adding the second rotate:
[image: After adding the 2nd rotate]

```
class MyRotateContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyRotateContainerState createState() => new _MyRotateContainerState();
}

class _MyRotateContainerState extends State<MyRotateContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double angle = 30.0 * pi / 180.0;

    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: angle,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: -angle,
          child: Text(
            'SOME TEXT',
            textScaleFactor: 2.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Applying the inverse transform to the child is the right way and probably the only way of doing it. If your transform is more ocmplicated, you can assign it to a `final Matrix4 myTransform = ...`. You can use [this constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.html) for the parent. For the child use the same constructor but pass `Matrix4.inverted(myTransform)`. This way you don't have to do the inverse transform by hand, or by brain :)