# Flutter ignore Transform from child widget

Tags: flutter

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uQSq.png) & i want 
[screen like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MfmC.jpg) I am adding close button on my image, In which i had used Transform to scale image, but i don't want to change the size of close button. How to ignore scaling on close button?

Comment: Maybe having a `Stack` widget, and inside that, the Close Button alongside the Transform+Image widget. This should give you a similar layout

Comment: Please upload your code.

Comment: I have used stack inside transform, so it applied to close button also. Because i can't use it outside of Transform, its required fullscreen area to move widget.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. Move the close box outside of the `Transform`, so that the `Transform` applies only to the image and not the close box, as was suggested by Amruth Pillai in the comments. This is the preferred way, if it is possible for your use case.
2. Otherwise, the inverse operation must be performed on the child. In other words, whatever scale is applied to the outer transform, the reciprocal scale needs to be applied to the child. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260674/3558355) for an example dealing with rotation. The principle is the same for scaling. In your code, and assuming uniform scaling in the x and y axes, you might do something like:

```
...
child: Container(
  child: Transform.scale(
    scale: 1.0 / notifier.value.entry(0, 0),
    child: IconButton( ... ),
  ),
),
...
)
```